# Magento : Assigning products to (new) websites programmatically do I need to run an index and which one?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, reindex

In Magento When assigning products to (new) websites programmatically do I need to run an index and which one?

When using

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts(array($set_to_store_id), $product->getId());
```

1. Can I then programmatically trigger an index? (for the current $product)
2. And if I would want to do it in the backend which index is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this reindexing programmatically :

> catalog_product_attribute

If you want to do from admin, then you can also do it.

Comment: Suppose I update the product. How can I mark the product as changed for this particular index (only) and make sure it gets reindexed.

Comment: Or does the update using above code already trigger indexing implicitly

Comment: you can try above thing, so you will get idea.